# TypeError: expected string when using re.findall on web page text -- why?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn how to screen-scrape with BeautifulSoup.

---

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.feedburner.com/zenhabits').read()

patFinderTitle = re.compile('<h4 class="itemtitle"><a href=(.*)</a></h4>')

findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle,webpage)
listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(1, 5)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i]
    print("\n")
```

---

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//da-srv1/users/xxxxx/Desktop/fetcher", line 14, in <module>
print findPatTitle[i]
**IndexError: list index out of range**
```

---

Comment: `urlopen('http://feeds.feedburner.com/zenhabits').read` is the name of a method. I suspect what you are looking for is `urlopen('http://feeds.feedburner.com/zenhabits').read()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following expression:

```
patFinderTitle.findall(webpage)
```

You can't do the equivalent of `re.findall(re.compile(<expression>), <string>)` since `re.findall` only accepts a regular expression as a string -- and `re.compile(<expression>)` returns a compiled regex object. So you need to use your compiled regex object `patFinderTitle` and call its `findall()` method (see above).

EDIT: Oh. Turns out you *can* do `re.findall(re.compile(<expression>), <string>)`. The more you know.

Comment: I tried, but it comes up with this: TypeError: findall() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Jerry: obviously not — re.compile(<expression>).findall() definitely only takes a minimum of one argument.

Comment: `self` counts as an argument. You'd get the error he describes if you run `patFinderTitle.findall()`.

Comment: bukzor -- I meant `re.compile(<expression>).findall` definitely only takes a minimum of one argument. Sorry for the miscommunication

Answer (score 2):

You left out the parenthesis on the read() function call, so webpage was a function and not a string.

```
webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.feedburner.com/zenhabits').read()
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Unfortunately, now I'm getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//da-srv1/users/mwseymour/Desktop/cnnfetcher", line 14, in <module>
    print findPatTitle[i]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: @jerry: there were no match for your regex pattern. findPatTitle is [].